# Collada model increases the brightness of THREE scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

Why does the brightness of a THREE scene increase when you add a collada model?

When I run the scene without a model, the light works as expected, but when I add one, the brightness of the scene goes up a great deal.

This is the model that I use:

https://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/detail/eoss-messenger

Light and collada loader code:

```
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040, 3.5 ) );

    let loader = new ColladaLoader();
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load('./models/MESSENGER/MESSENGER.dae', ( collada ) => {

      dae = collada.scene;
      dae.scale.set( 1 / 90, 1 / 90, 1 / 90);

    });
```

Comment: Possibly, there are light sources in the loaded collada object. Your ambient light plus those light sources, the result is hight brightness of the scene.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it!

Comment: And just a small remark ) You can apply scaling to all axis at once with the `.setScalar()` method. For example: `dae.scale.setScalar( 1 / 90 );` [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/ef06wzLu/)

Comment: Neat, and thanks for the fiddle!

Comment: I should also mention that I managed to get rid of the excess light using Blender, in case anybody runs into the same issue!

Comment: You could describe the solution in an answer about what and how you've done )